# How to request LtpaToken2 from an application hosted on WebSphere

Tags: websphere, ltpa

Can anyone please let me know if it is possible to request a LtpaToken2 from an application hosted on WebSphere?

I have a vb.net client application which is using a REST API hosted on WebSphere. I initially connect to the API with the user name and password using basic authentication. Using the same basic authentication is it possible to request a LtpaToken2 from WebSphere so that I can use it for subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you do the authentication using an HTTP Request, you will get the cookies (along with LTPA token) in the response. This is true with a web browser, or with any client application.
The response cookies can be stored on the client side, and send it in the subsequent requests (as part of request headers) to WAS.

While designing this, it will be better you have a common gateway in your Client App through which all the calls to WAS goes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I am able to see the token in the response cookies.